# Unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an unramified (finite) extension from $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Is is equivalent to saying $\mathbb Q_p\to K$ is an unramified ring homomorphism? Or it is equivalent to saying $\mathbb Z_p\to \mathcal O_K$ is unramified ring homomorphism?

Comment: You need to be using the morphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathcal{O}_K$ because the statement is silly for fields. But with this modification, yes.

Comment: Thank you! So why that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $k'/k$ is a finite separable extension of fields, the corresponding homomorphism $k \to k'$ is always unramified.

Suppose that $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified. Then this is the case if and only if the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is equal to $p\mathcal{O}_K$, (the extension of residue fields is always separable) so $\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathcal{O}_K$ is an unramified local homomorphism if and only if $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified.

Since both rings are complete with respect to their maximal ideals being an unramified *local* homomorphism is equivalent to being an unramified *ring* homomorphism see [StacksProject Lemma 41.3.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/039I).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. So what will be the easiest definition of unramifiedness to see that the field case is trivially unramified? I tried to compute the Kähler differential which seems not that easy.

Comment: @CO2 I was thinking locally, I have removed the statement in case it's not correct, but I still feel like i'd have seen it if it were true.

Comment: It is true that it for any finite separabel extension $F/K$, $\Omega_{F/K}^1=0$, cf., https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/090W. But I just feel it is not so easy to compute the Kähler differential in general. This object is a bit intransparent for me.

Comment: But thank you for pointing out there is also a definition for unramified local homomorphism.

Comment: @CO2 ah yes of course, what was i thinking. It might help you to think somewhat geometrically about $\Omega^1$ as the cotangent sheaf when you take $Spec$ (maybe do it in some cases of polynomial rings over a field)